# Why is pip still not recognized even though it is on my path?

Tags: python, pip

I ran the [get-pip](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) python file, and it told me that

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

So, I added that to my path. However, whenever I try to run a `pip` command, I get the error:

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Here is what happens when I `echo` my path:

```
echo %Path%
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Python27;C:\Users\cstaheli\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\Users\cstaheli\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

As you can see, the last one is `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`. So, I can't figure out why it is still not recognized by Windows.

Let me know if you need more information to solve this issue.

Comment: Is this running successfully `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip.exe` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This says that module `pip` installed:

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python27\lib\site-packages

This says that there is no command `pip` in `path` (`pip.exe` is in `C:\Python27\Scripts`):

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

You can run `python -m pip` or add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to `path`.

Comment: Aha. That was it. I found lots of tutorials on how to install pip, but not what to do if it was already installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this format "pip.main(['install', '--user', 'httpie'])" if you want to use the pip command locally, you can substitute the httpie with whatever module or dependency you want, please see below link for more info.

[installing requests module for python 2.7.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45450231/installing-requests-module-for-python-2-7-13)