# installing requests module for python 2.7.13

Tags: python, python-2.7

[Python-2.7]
I was trying to install the requests module in python using the following commands

> > > import pip
> > >       pip.main(['install', 'requests'])
> > >       and I run in to these issues:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certifi-2017.7.27.1.dist-info'
2
```

Can anyone help me? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installing request module in python 2.7 windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345763/installing-request-module-in-python-2-7-windows)

Comment: Thank you, Ivan Kolesnikov for editing my error code above,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either run this program as superuser or install this package locally (with the `--user` flag)

```
import pip; 
pip.main(['install', '--user', 'requests'])
```

The problem here is that pip cannot write files to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` because it doesn't have enough privileges.

Comment: Thank you very much @Morreski, I was really frustrated. It worked when I used the "--user" flag. Really appreciated.